# How to avoid nested loops

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I need to construct this object wit the has and repo. I feel like nesting these maps is a really bad practice, and it's the point of failure for the flow. How should this be written?

```
let observ = observable$.flatMap(repos => {
  return Rx.Observable.from(repos.map(repo => ({hash: getHash(repo), repo})))
})
```

Comment: I don't know RxJs, so I can't speak to whether it's a bad practice from the perspective of that community, but I don't see anything wrong with the nesting.  If that bothers you, why not pull the lambdas into named functions and pass those into `flatMap` and `map`?

Comment: What's the type of `repos`, its `map` method, and `getHash`?

Comment: @Bergi `repos` is an `array`, it's map is the `array.prototype.map`, `getHash` is a function that returns a string.

Comment: I posted the full code in code review http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/122873/preforming-some-async-operations-with-rx-js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see anything explicitly wrong with this approach. If you would like to simplify the code, you can use `concatMap`, which will transform a stream of arrays to a stream of the items. We can then just do a normal map:

```
let repo$ = observable$.concatMap(identity);
let observ = repo$.map(repo => ({hash: getHash(repo), repo }));
```

Where `identity === x => x`.

You can also apply `concatMap` earlier in your chain when constructing the `observable$` stream if you want to avoid calling it with `identity`.

Comment: Only `flatmap(id)` has type `Observable<Observable<T1>> => Observable<T1>`, usually you don't have observables of observables. It seems to me that OP used `flatmap` of the type `Observable<Repo>, (Repo => List<{hash, repo}>) =>  Observable<{hash, repo}>` - not to an observable of lists.